# How can I access the GitHub icons?

Tags: css, github, sass

I would like to use the GitHub icons listed [here](https://github.com/styleguide/css/7.0). Ideally I'd like to use the GitHub styleguide's icon classes to insert the icons. Where do I get the GitHub `CSS` or `SCSS` stylesheet for these icons?

I don't see a download link anywhere on those pages...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The download link is in the black bar saying "7.1". However the download link is broken, so my suggestion would be to send Github a mail requesting the new URL.

Comment: Good, I'm not crazy! That's the URL I visited but I thought I was looking in the wrong place...

Comment: No, you're not crazy :) Hopefully you will get a reply from them soon!

Comment: I guess GitHub still has not addressed this broken link.  Does anyone have any insight as to why?